# combine div ID and this.ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe isn't good title for the question but my problem is exactly this.
I have several DIV tags on the page and all of them start as #result and continue with number `<div id="result22">`, `<div id="result33">` etc. Now I'm find some nice jQuery things to do and it works as expected but the only problem is how to add known number to the `#result`
here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.like').bind('click', function () {
       $.get("/sng_like/"+this.id+"/", function(data) {
         $('#result')[0].innerHTML=data;
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

I want that value of `this.id` to be a part of the `#result` to get `#result22` for example.
My JS knowledge is limited and I was already try `$('#result'+this.id)[0].innerHTML=data;` but it wont work.

Thanks,
G

Comment: you need to store a reference to `this` before entering the anonymous get function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.like').bind('click', function () {
       var item=$(this);
       $.get("/sng_like/"+item.attr("id")+"/", function(data) {
         $('#result'+item.attr("id")).html(data);
     });
   });
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. So you may consider using that.

If you are using 1.7+ version, your code can be rewritten to use on function like this

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".like",function(){
       var item=$(this);           
       $.get("/sng_like/"+item.attr("id")+"/", function(data) {
          $('#result'+item.attr("id")).html(data);
       });
   });
});
```

`$(function()` is a short form of `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Probably should be using `item.prop("id")`, or just stash the "id" value itself since that's all that's needed.

Comment: Also note that event delegation is not necessary here. `$('.like').on('click', ...)` or `$('.like').click(...)` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

```
$.get("/sng_like/"+$(this).attr("id")+"/", function(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.like').on('click', function() {
           var MyId=this.id;
           $.get("/sng_like/"+MyId+"/", function(data) {
               $('#result'+MyId).html(data);
           });
       });
   });
</script>
```